# To have hyperlink in the exported svg file

Tags: svg, bpmn-js

I'm using bpmn-to-image to convert bpmn file to svg and then using the svg to incorporate my diagram into mkdocs and hence to complete my technical process documentation.

However i would like to explore how to add link / hyperlink into the diagram's intermediate event such that it can be clicked (interactive) within the svg.

In draw.io i can easily do it by right click any shape and add link, however camunda modeler doesn't allow me to do so, hence i believe that we can first put the link into the node's documentation and then customize a program to read out this documentation content to populate it into a link which in svg it will create something like the following:

`<a xlink:href="#crprocess_development_configuration">`

But i don't know how, please shed me some light?